# gremlin hasLabel query times out

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have a test graph with less than a million nodes and probably a slightly higher number of edges. I'm using a remote gremlin client to connect to a janusgraph/gremlin-server instance backed by 3 scylla backends.

I have various different labeled nodes i.e url, domain, host and brand. The graph contains mainly url, domain, and host nodes. I have one brand node in this entire graph. The brand node looks like this:

```
{
    label: brand 
    properties: {
        brand: string
    }
}
```

I am able to do the following query in 1.5 ms. The brand property has a composite index.

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand').has('brand','stackoverflow');
```

The query below hits the 30s timeout. I expect this query to only return only one result based on the data I imported into the graph. I verified by testing with a limit

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand')
```

**My questions**

- Why does this timeout?
- Is Janusgraph scanning through all nodes in the graph to try find a single node labeled 'brand'? Is there no default index on labels?
- Why does the first query execute fine when the first steps for both are the same?

Thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, through what interface is this query timing out? I know that when I was working through Gremlin-Server on PHP I would get timeouts when it tries to return the full set of information. It might resolve by appending a `.next()`to the end of your second query, since it will provide the context of the query to return out to your program which called it the value of an individual vertex.

Comment: I was using the gremlin console connecting to a remote janusgraph. As far as I understand, the console should auto-iterate your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why does this timeout?
- Is Janusgraph scanning through all nodes in
  the graph to try find a single node labeled 'brand'? Is there no
  default index on labels?

As you have guessed this is likely timing out due to a full graph scan since vertex labels are not indexed in JanusGraph.  There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/283

- Why does the first query execute fine when the first steps for both are the same?

In this case I suspect that JanusGraph's optimizer is able to optimize the traversal plan to use the composite index.